# Создание и запуск метода при помощи JNI

Tags: java, c++, jni

Изучал `Java`, там была тема про `JNI` (мало написано). Мне суть понравилась, решил попробовать, долго искал в `google`, так ничего и не нашел (или можно сказать не понял). Есть такой код на `java`:

```
public class Main{

static{
    System.loadLibrary("lib.dll");
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    printString("TEST!\n")
}

}
```

На C++ хотел написать такой метод

```
void printString(string str){
  std::cout << str;
}
```

Как скомпилировать в `dll` и написать этот метод?

Comment: Я пишу под Windows я не Linux или Android, Во вторых мой вопрос можно задать проще - как работать с JNI

Comment: Конкретно под ваш вопрос есть [пример](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/222092) у Майкрософта.

Comment: @Flowneee, Спасибо!